# LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle not authenticating and redirecting to login

Tags: php, symfony, ssh-keys, lexikjwtauthbundle

I'm not sure if its my firewall setting or private keys, it was working then I deleted the directory and cloned from master had to copy my var/jwt directory directly over I think i forgot to commit it or something but now I can get a token

```
curl --request GET   --url http://localhost/api/private   --header 'authorization: Bearer TOKEN'
```

but when trying to use the token from command line curl or php get redirected back to login page

I tried setting my ..private/public keys to 600 but did not help my firewall shouldn't have changed

```
security:
encoders:
    AccountBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt
providers:
    account_users:
        entity: { class: AccountBundle\Entity\User, property: email}
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    login:
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        form_login:
            check_path:               /api/login_check
            username_parameter:       _username
            password_parameter:       _password
            success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            require_previous_session: false

    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

    main:
        anonymous: ~

        guard:
            authenticators:
              - account.security.guard.authenticator.account_form_login_authenticator


        logout:
            path: security_logout





access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

log shows

```
[2017-06-30 13:08:55] security.DEBUG: Access denied, the user is not fully authenticated; redirecting to authentication entry point. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AccessDeniedException(code: 403): Access Denied.
```

Comment: tried deleting and recreating the keys but did not help

Comment: seems to be something with firewall because its not even checking the token, but I can generate it